# In PHP / CodeIgniter more than one transaction started without completing the other; Such as nested transaction

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, hmvc

I am using HMVC in Codeigniter 
Which have model of inv_module and one is common model

Firstly the `$this->inv_module->model` stores some data in the database, with the mysql transaction;

 then modal call of the `$this->common->modal` before the transaction is complete of `$this->inv_module->model`, there is also a mysql transaction.

Can anyone tell me that what will happen when my first transaction is not completed and the transaction of the common model is start ?

my situation like this -

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->insert('tbl_categories', $category_array);

    $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->CI->db->insert('tbl_macro',$macro_array);
    $this->db->trans_complete();

$this->db->trans_complete();
```

This code call from another model -

```
$this->db->trans_start();
    $this->CI->db->insert('tbl_macro',$macro_array);
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

please any one help me

Comment: There is two different transactions. If the second fail, it will have no effects on the first unless you do to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested transaction will commit or fail only on itself.

The "outer" transaction will still be valid.

Comment: But if the nested transaction placed in a loaded library function then outer transaction not rolled back. do you have any idea about this case?